# Unexpected Javascript RegExp behavior

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I create a RegExp object (in JavaScript) to test for the presence of a number:

```
var test = new RegExp( '[0-9]', 'g' );
```

I use it like this

```
console.log( test.test( '0' ) ); // true
console.log( test.test( '1' ) ); // false - why?
```

The output of this is even more confusing:

```
console.log( test.test( '1' ) ); // true
console.log( test.test( '0' ) ); // false - why?
console.log( test.test( '1' ) ); // true
console.log( test.test( '2' ) ); // false - why?
console.log( test.test( '2' ) ); // true - correct, but why is this one true?
```

If I remove the `g` qualifier, it behaves as expected.

Is this a bug as I believe it is, or some peculiar part of the spec? Is the `g` qualifier supposed to be used this way? (I'm re-using the same expression for multiple tasks, hence having the qualifier at all)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Description

> `test` called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

You can confirm this behavior:

```
var test = new RegExp( '[0-9]', 'g' );
test.test('01'); //true
test.test('01'); //true
test.test('01'); //false
```

It doesn't make sense to use the `g` flag if all you want is to confirm a single match against various strings.

Comment: Thanks. You were a couple of minutes behind jfriend00 but this seems like a more complete answer. Just waiting for the countdown to expire to accept!

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `'g'` flag.  When you use the `'g`' flag, it updates the `lastIndex` property of the regex (preparing for a successive search on the same string) and then starts the next search from that index value (thus giving you a false reading on your next search).

Similar question and answer here: [Why is Regex Javascript //g flag affecting state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873122/why-is-regex-javascript-g-flag-affecting-state)

Comment: Do you mean it ignores the input string the second time I call it, and continues to look for matches in the previously-given string? That's pretty weird

Comment: @Dave.  It's updating the `lastIndex` property in the regex object and starting the second match from there which gives you the false reading.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand now. I put a quick test together and it seems it uses the new string, but searches from the last matched index: http://jsfiddle.net/SnxSg/ This has got to be the weirdest behaviour ever, but at least I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test),

> As with `exec` (or in combination with it), `test` called multiple times
>   on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the
>   previous match.

Technically, the ECMAScript 5.1 spec says

> **[15.10.6.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3) RegExp.prototype.test(string)**
>
> The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let match be the result of evaluating the `RegExp.prototype.exec` (15.10.6.2) algorithm upon this RegExp object using *string* as the
>      argument.
> 2. If *match* is not null, then return `true`; else return `false`.
>
> **[15.10.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2) RegExp.prototype.exec(string)**
>
> Performs a regular expression match of *string* against the regular
>   expression and returns an Array object containing the results of the
>   match, or `null` if *string* did not match.
>
> The String ToString(*string*) is searched for an occurrence of the
>   regular expression pattern as follows:
>
> 1. Let *R* be this RegExp object.
> 2. [...]
> 3. [...]
> 4. Let *lastIndex* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *R* with argument "`lastIndex`".
> 5. Let *i* be the value of ToInteger(*lastIndex*).
> 6. Let *global* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *R* with argument "`global`".
> 7. If *global* is `false`, then let *i* = 0.
> 8. [...]
> 9. [...]
> 10. Let *e* be *r*'s *endIndex* value.
> 11. If *global* is `true`,
>
>     1. Call the [[Put]] internal method of *R* with arguments "`lastIndex`", *e*, and `true`.
> 12. [...]

Therefore, to avoid this behavior, you can

- Avoid using global flag `g`

  This way, at step 7, `i` will be `0` instead of `lastIndex`.
- Reset [`lastIndex`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.7.5) manually after each use

  > The value of the `lastIndex` property specifies the String position at
  >   which to start the next match.

  For example,

  ```
  var test = /[0-9]/g;
  test.test('0');      // true
  test.lastIndex;      // 1
  test.lastIndex = 0;
  test.test('1');      // true
  ```
- Use `match` or `search` string methods

  `match` resets `lastIndex` to 0, and `search` ignores it:

  > **[15.5.4.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2) String.prototype.match (regexp)**
  >
  > [...] [If] *global* is `true`, call the [[Put]] internal method of *rx* with arguments "`lastIndex`" and 0. [...]
  >
  > **[15.5.4.12](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.12) String.prototype.search (regexp)**
  >
  > [...] Search the value *string* from its beginning for an occurrence of the
  >   regular expression pattern *rx*. [...] The `lastIndex` and `global`
  >   properties of *regexp* are ignored when performing the search. [...]

  For example,

  ```
  var test = /[0-9]/g;
  test.test('0');        // true
  test.lastIndex;        // 1
  '0'.search(test) > -1; // true
  test.lastIndex;        // 1 (unaltered)
  !!'0'.match(test);     // true
  test.lastIndex;        // 0
  ```